# In the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, what counterexamples arise if certain conditions are not met?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Concerning the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, what counterexamples arise if certain conditions are not met?

In the context of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, what counterexamples arise in the absence of completeness conditions (or when X lacks any Baire second category set)? Alternatively, when considering a non-linear family of operators, what specific instances of counterexamples manifest?

Comment: I seem to recall that in locally convex spaces, the concept of "barelled space"  (espaces tonnelés) was invented so that these arguments would still work.